# Grequests: importerror

Tags: python, importerror, grequests

I am working with grequests for the first time. I installed it with pip, which looked fine, but when I run my script I get:

> ImportError: No module named grequests

Any thoughts about this one?

Comment: Is pip installing to the same Python that you're running? ie, do you have pip set to Python2.7 and your system Python is 2.6 etc...

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling `grequests`, I still had the problem. I thought that `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` was the system installed version, but it's not.

I needed to delete that and remove it from `~/.bash_profile` that and then everything worked fine. I don't know if that was my only problem as the reinstall could have fixed something, but I think it was

> Note:you said that you installed it with pip, which looked fine.but
>   may some additional library packages are necessary  You need to
>   install `libevent`, which on Ubuntu can be done with:
>
> ```
> apt-get install libevent-dev
> ```
>
> Alternatively, to install `gevent` and all it's dependencies automatically:
>
> ```
> apt-get install python-gevent
> ```